# Which one is the grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: definite-article

Which one is the grammatically correct sentence?
1) watch the television.
2) watch television.

Comment: Both are correct, but they mean different things. For example, I might say "watch the television," if the TV is flickering intermittently, and I want another person to also see it happen, or if I'm in the middle of moving and want another person to safeguard the TV in my absence. But for the common activity of watching television, you omit the article.

Answer (score 2):

The [definite article](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/definite_article.htm) 'The' is used before a noun to define it as something specific

"watch the television" means you are watching a specific television set (keeping an eye on it also qualifies as watching, and the television doesn't even have to be on)

"watch television" refers to 'the act of watching programs on T.V (on any television)